issue related to focus in tizen, using javascript
When my focus is on the menu bar and I am pressing the right key, focus is skipping the first item_row i.e. from the menu bar it goes to row_item_1_1, skipping row_item_1_0 and from menu to item_row_2_1 skipping item_row_2_0 and so on.
How can I resolve this issue?
case "ArrowRight": // Right button
  if (
    $(".sidebar-container").hasClass("toggle_menu") &&
    $("[id^=menu_]").is(":focus")
  ) {
    if ($(".profile_container").hasClass("active")) {
      var $logoutButton = $("#logout-button");
      if ($logoutButton.length) {
        console.log("element found with id #logout-button");
        $logoutButton.focus();
      }
    } else SN.focus(`#${first_page_focused_element}`);
  }

  e.preventDefault();
  break; 


We can't help you to solve this without also seeing the relevant HTML

Hello, would you share your dev environment? simlator or TV device? Tizen Version? Which tools - Tizen Studio ? etc
